# Mouse not acting the way it used to on google chrome

Tags: mouse

my mouse is not doing everything that it used to on google chrome and I don't know why. Here is a screenshot of the main areas I am having trouble with:

[image: Mouse_Error]

When I click on the tabs, it's supposed to open the webpage, but instead it closes the page entirely. Also it doesn't click sometimes and used to work just fine. I found this code, but it is a work around because I have to do it every time:

```
metacity --replace &
```

Then when I am done, have to go back to compiz to see my applications on the sidebar again:

```
compiz --replace &
```

It helps make the mouse click though, so I thought I would share that. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you all in advance, I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you have a problem with your mouse. The micro-switches in a mouse are mostly cheap stuff (even in expensive models)
and not properly capsuled. Just a bit of dust or dirt in the micro-switch can lead to not intended double-clicks.
It will happen sometimes or often, sometimes the mouse works without a problem. Try a different mouse to check if the problem persists.

Do you have `Chrome Toolbox` installed? In the `Chrome Toolbox` options general tab you can disable `Doubleclick on tab to close it`.

Comment: @mook765-How would I check to see if I have Chrome Toolbox installed? I don't think I do, but I guess it's a possibility.

Comment: Click the `wrench icon`,  choose `Settings`, then choose `Extensions`

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Yes thank you. It turned out that I did not have that program installed, but I did have an extra mouse on hand. I experimented with your idea and it works much better.

Comment: It is even possible to clean the micro-switch, but not too easy, you need to find hidden screws to open the mouse.
the switch is pretty tiny, disassembly is mostly possible. Look for some you-tube videos about that before you do.